# Go code how to connect a self signed cert SSL site without InsecureSkipVerify?

Tags: go, ssl

in a project I need to program in Go code to connect a https site which is deployed with a self-signed TLS certs; I am provided the server certs files: (the `ca.cert` `ca.key`, `client.cert` `client.key` `client.csr` and server configured with `server.cert` `server.key` `server.csr`);

I have figured out the following code indeed works

```
cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("./client.crt", "./client.key")
// if err != nil { ... }

rootCAs := x509.NewCertPool()
certs, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./ca.crt")
// if err != nil { ... }
// Append our cert to the system pool
if ok := rootCAs.AppendCertsFromPEM(certs); !ok { ... }
config := tls.Config{
    Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
    InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    ServerName: "ingress.local",
    RootCAs:    rootCAs,
}
conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "some-site.xyz:443", &config)
if err != nil {
    if x509err, ok := err.(x509.UnknownAuthorityError); ok {
        fmt.Printf("unknown rootCert: %#v\n", x509err.Cert)
    }
    log.Fatalf("client: dial: %#v\n\t%+v", err, err)
}

tr := &http.Transport{TLSClientConfig: &config}
client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}

// Uses local self-signed cert
req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, "https://some-site.xyz", nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("client: http new request: %#v", err, err)
}
```

now the question is: if I don't set the `InsecureSkipVerify: true` in tls.Config, the code failed with errors:
1. if not set `ServerName` correctly, it's `x509.HostnameError`
    this service is running with a k8s ingress, and I figured out the correct hostname is `ingress.local`
2. even if I set `ServerName` correctly, it now failed with `x509.UnknownAuthorityError`

The other way I've tried is to not loading `ca.cert` at all, only 1 line of `InsecureSkipVerify: true` can make all of this working, and only required files are the `client.cert` `client.key`

if I set only the `InsecureSkipVerify: true` without loading the client certs, that results an `400 Bad Request No required SSL certificate was sent` proved that server side is configured with requiring the client certs;

```
cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("./client.crt", "./client.key")
config := tls.Config{
    Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
    InsecureSkipVerify: true,
}
// same tls.Dial or http.NewRequest works well ...
```

I want to try the best effort to avoid setting `InsecureSkipVerify: true` wonder is there any way possible to make it working without `InsecureSkipVerify: true`?   Is the way above of loading `ca.cert` into a CertPool has anything wrong?  the provided files include `ca.key` and `*.csr` files as well, but from all online existing TLS connection go code samples I don't see where can they be useful ?

If there's no way to make it working without `InsecureSkipVerify: true`, then is it still meaningful to load the `ca.cert` ?

**Update one more thing**:   I've tried with `curl --cacert ./ca.crt --cert ./client.crt --key client.key https://some-site.xyz -k` got same with above Go code, that is together with `-k` (`--insecure`) it works, with cacert or without; but without `-k` it got similar errors:

```
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: ./ca.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect some-site.xyz:443` and ensure it's the right certificate with the right CA.

Comment: set the tls.Config ServerName field to match the CN you expect of the other side.  That is how "sni" support is done with this library as well.

Comment: and add ClientCAs.  RootCAs and ClientCAs both need to be set.  Once you get it all right (including ServerName), you can turn off InsecureSkipVerify.  Note that you usually have 3 files (cert, key, trust).  But it really should be 4: (cert, rootcas, key, clientcas).  The cert chain of your own cert may be totally different from the one you trust as client.  ie: server has LetsEncrypt, clients are issued by your company.